# Iphone Messaging

Tags: iphone

Is there any way in IOS SDK that, i can access my mobile messages from my mobile inbox in my application.

If any one know please help.

Thanks in advance 
Abhishek kumar srivastava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than being jailbroken or using Private APIs, no.